# How to make an user-defined input in Class Stock

Tags: java, oop

I'm having trouble doing a user-defined method in my program here, would it be nice if anyone can help me

```
package Ex_9_2;



public class TestStock {
public static String price;

//main
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stock stock = new Stock("ORCL", "Oracle Corporation");

    System.out.println("Please enter previous closing price ");
    stock.setPreviousClosingPrice(34.5);

    System.out.println("Please enter current price ");
    stock.setCurrentPrice(34.35);
    System.out.println(stock);

    // Display stock info
    System.out.println("Previous Closing Price: " + stock.getPreviousClosingPrice());
    System.out.println("Current Price: " + stock.getCurrentPrice());
    System.out.println("Price Change: " + stock.changePercent());
 }
}
```

Here's my other class

```
package Ex_9_2;

public class Stock {
private String symbol;
private String name;
private double previousClosingPrice;
private double currentPrice;

public Stock() {
}

public Stock(String symbol, String name) {
this.symbol = symbol;
this.name = name;
}

public String getSymbol() {
    return this.symbol;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public double getPreviousClosingPrice() {
    return previousClosingPrice;
}

public double getCurrentPrice() {
    return currentPrice;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setPreviousClosingPrice(double price) {
      this.previousClosingPrice = price;
}

public void setCurrentPrice(double price) {
      this.currentPrice = price;
}

public double changePercent() {
    return (currentPrice - previousClosingPrice) / previousClosingPrice;
}

@Override
public java.lang.String toString(){
    return "\nYour Company's name is " + this.name
            + "\nYour Company's Symbol is " + this.symbol;

}
```

I can't seem to make a user-input in my main for this problem:

```
System.out.println("Please enter previous closing price ");
stock.setPreviousClosingPrice(34.5);
```

and this:

```
System.out.println("Please enter current price ");
stock.setCurrentPrice(34.35);
```

please help,

Comment: What do you mean by "make a user-input in my main for this problem"? Where is the problem? Do you want to take input from the user instead of the hard-coded "stock.setPreviousClosingPrice(34.5)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **java.util.Scanner** class to take inputs from the user.
Declare a Scanner variable in your main function:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then use scan.nexDouble() for taking input from the user. For example:

```
System.out.println("Please enter previous closing price ");
stock.setPreviousClosingPrice(scan.nextDouble());
```

Comment: That means I have to make another class called "java.utill.Scanner"?

Comment: No, Scanner is included in the standard java.util package. Just import it in your TestStock class using: "import java.util.Scanner;"

Comment: @AceShafiq it is a built in class in java. You use the import to import the `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: oh, I see. Okay I will try. Sorry, I'm new to this Language so I'm a bit to dizzy how to put input and output since I only learned C++.

Comment: Thank You for the Help. ^_^